# Playing CSS animation on button click won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to call a CSS animation on the event that this button is pressed, after doing some research it seems classList is the way forward. It's late and I think I'm being stupid but I cannot get it to work.

HTML:

```
<body>
<img id="myID" class="mouse" src="mouse.png" onclick="ani()">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ani()
{
  document.getElementById('myID').classList.add = 'animate';
}
```

CSS:

```
.animate
{
  animation: test 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes test
{
  100%
{
  transform: translateX(calc(8%));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add is a function so the way you are using classList needs a slight change from:

```
document.getElementById('myID').classList.add = 'animate';
```

to:

```
document.getElementById('myID').classList.add('animate');
```

```js
function ani(){
  document.getElementById('myID').classList.add('animate');
}
```

```css
.animate {
  animation: test 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes test {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(8%));
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <img id="myID" class="mouse" src="https://stock.wikimini.org/w/images/d/d4/Mickey_Mouse.png" onclick="ani()">
</body>
```

Comment: Still having no luck unfortunately.. I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

Comment: someone has kindly added a snippet to show what happens. Could you try that and then describe what isn't working for you? One thing is, are you expecting a second click to do something animation-wise?